# Maximal ideals correspond to G-orbits

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field and $\overline{\mathbb{F}}$ its algebraic closure. I denote with $G = \text{Aut}_\mathbb{F}(\overline{\mathbb{F}})$ the automorphism group.
I have to show that
$$
\text{Max} \; \mathbb{F}[x_1,\cdots,x_n] = \overline{\mathbb{F}^n}/G.
$$
By Max I denote the maximum spectrum, thus all maximal ideals of the polynomial ring. Further I would like to construct examples to understand this fact better using $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$ and $\overline{\mathbb{F}} = \mathbb{C}$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Hint*: Define a map
$
\theta: \bar{\mathbb F}^n \rightarrow Max \mathbb F[x_1,\dots x_n]
$ by 
$
\theta(\vec x) = ker (e_{\vec x})
$
where $e_{\vec x}$ is the $\vec x$ valuation map.

Answer (score 0):

I ask for patience, as I am a beginner.
I almost got it.
We define
$$\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{F}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]) := \{f \vert \mathbb{F}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]: \mathbb{F}[x_1,\cdots,x_n] \rightarrow K \; \vert \; \text{just for all elements in the polynomial ring} \}.$$

These are the regular functions. Then a maximal ideal would be a polynomial on this set, which evaluates to zero, such that:
$$
\mathfrak{m} := \{f \in \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{F}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]) \; \vert \; f(x) = 0\}.
$$
The maximal spectrum is just all of these ideals, as I said. I understand now, that I seek $\theta: \overline{\mathbb{F}^n} \rightarrow \text{Max} \; \mathbb{F}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, as on the right side I have all polynomials that evaluate to zero on the entire ring, thus the kernel of the evaluation, which eduard mentioned in the comments.
Now a polynomial in $n$-variables looks like $\sum_{k = (k_1,\ldots,k_n) \in \mathbb{N}^n_0}a_k x^{k_1}_1 \cdots x^{k_n}_n$. When does this guy evaluate to zero then? If all summand evaluate to zero. Thus it is enough that all $a_i$ are zero. I assume that every summand is zero by some translation. As we are in a commutative group, right and left translation are the same thing and we see, that this is the factor group of $\overline{F}^n/\text{Aut}_{F}(\overline{\mathbb{F}})$.

Is this correct? 
How can this be written down in a proper form?

Comment: What does $f| \mathbb F[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ stand for?

Comment: This is supposed to be a polynomial restricted to the ring of polynomials. It is superfluous, I guess.

Comment: I think that many things make no sense. How is that restriction defined. A maximal ideal is a polynomial?